# How to auto play youtube video in amazon fire tv

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, autoplay, amazon-fire-tv

I used this url `http://www.youtube.com/embed/uGNhirSbWW0?autoplay=1` to auto play this video in my amazon fireTv app using web View, i am getting the video but the video is not playing automatically? How to auto play the video in amazon firetv. any other way to play the youtube video

Comment: Have you got any solution

Answer (score 0):

For someone who stumbled upon this problem when using **Amazon Web Apps**:

Somewhere in your code load `Iframe Player API` code

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
```

Create an iframe and call `event.target.playVideo()` when `onReady` event fires

```
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }
```

[Reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)